# Iphone App url in Alert Prompt instead of App name

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

I am creating an iPhone app using HTML5, jQuery mobile, CSS and Xcode. I want to show user current position on Google maps. When I use this function

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

in confirmation prompt its shows app URL instead of app name.

Kindly guide me how to show app name in prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working in ios alert with app name.

```
$(document).ready(function(){                      

   $(function(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   })

   function onDeviceReady() {       
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);       
   }               
});
```